# undefined method "<" в Ruby

Tags: ruby

В блоке if выдает ошибку undefined method "<"

```
if @word63[x]<0 and i==9
```

Вот полный метод

```
 def search
        minus=[]
       @word63.each_index do |x|
         if @word63[x]<0
           x+=1
           10.times do |i|
             if i==0
               minus[0]=x
             end
             if @word63[x]<0 and i==9
               minus[1]=x
             end
             x+=1
           end
         end
       end
      end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы выходите за пределы массива, то есть в определённый момент
`x` становится больше `@word63.length - 1`.

Например,

`@word63 = [1, 2, -5, 34, 5]`

При `x == 2` выражение `@word63[x] < 0` вернёт `true`и мы успешно попадём в итоге в блок итератора `10.times`. И каждый раз в нём(а итераций напомню 10) `x` увеличивается на 1 (`x+=1`). Наступит момент, когда `x == 5` и в выражении `@word63[x]<0 and i==9` мы обращаемся к `@word63[5]`, а `@word63[5]` вернёт нам `nil`, так как элемента с таким индексом нет. Соответственно и метода `<` нет у объекта `nil:NilClass`.